# Writing a Custom Stata Scheme

Tags: stata

I'm writing a custom Stata scheme for work and I have one specific and one general question.

Specific: How do I set it my scheme so that no y-axis title is generated by default? This would imitate the graph option, "ytitle("")"

General: Does some sort of scheme documentation exist?

I've been creating my scheme by altering s2color, comparing other schemes and changing options one by one to see how my graph changes. The closest thing to documentation I've found is someone on statalist asking for documentation in 2003 and being told that it would take a bit longer than three weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your general question, a good starting point is the command *help scheme entries*
This set of slides is also helpful
http://www.stata.com/meeting/portugal10/portugal10_rising.pdf

Comment: Opening and closing messages such as you might find in person-to-person emails and letters are not needed here. Please leave them out. No one experienced will infer lack of any good will or good manners. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts